# Web application where or which thread using ram on IIS at running

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I have a web application, and deployed on IIS.I looked at task manager, Application ram is every second is increase 0.2-0.3 mb and when get requests higher more. My question is how to find which metod, variable, or cookie store data on ram. May i get on debug or IIS logs? Thanks all answers.

Comment: What kind of web application? For .NET Core you need to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak

Comment: Please consider asking a more precise question, as @LexLi proposes. It is too broad in its current form

Comment: I think you need to to capture several dump files to narrow down the problem. You can monitor which thread is running all the time and what managed method it is calling. Besides, the dump obj stack will help you fix the high memory issue. Debug diagnostic tool also can help generate primary dump analysis report.